# R: Values on Graph Do Not Match Data

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data:

```
var1 = c(5,5,8,13,14,12,11,10,9,9,8,8)
var2 = c(13,13,22,30,35,31,25,24,20,20,20,21)

var1 <- ts(var1, start = 2010, frequency = 12)
var2 <- ts(var2, start = 2010, frequency = 12)

df = cbind(var1,var2)

        var1 var2
Jan 2010    5   13
Feb 2010    5   13
Mar 2010    8   22
Apr 2010   13   30
May 2010   14   35
Jun 2010   12   31
Jul 2010   11   25
Aug 2010   10   24
Sep 2010    9   20
Oct 2010    9   20
Nov 2010    8   20
Dec 2010    8   21
```

I then made the following graph for this data:

```
library(dygraphs)

dygraph(df, main = "Stacked Graph") %>%
  dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
  dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

[image]

**My Question:** When I look at the graph of this data, I see that the green values almost approach "50" - yet, the largest value is the entire dataset is only 35.

I am not interested in adding the two variables (var1,var2) together - I just want to plot their values using a stacked time series plot.

**Can someone please show me how to fix this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either omit the `dyOptions()` call completely or
set the `stackedGraph` argument in it to `FALSE`.

A stacked plot means that the values of the serieses are
added/summed. By turning that feature of you get the plain
series values.

You can set the `fillGraph` argument in `dySeries()` to `TRUE`, to
color the area under the line.

```r
var1 = c(5,5,8,13,14,12,11,10,9,9,8,8)
var2 = c(13,13,22,30,35,31,25,24,20,20,20,21)

var1 <- ts(var1, start = 2010, frequency = 12)
var2 <- ts(var2, start = 2010, frequency = 12)

df = cbind(var1,var2)

library(dygraphs)

dygraph(df, main = "Graph") %>%
  dySeries("var1", label = "Var1", fillGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dySeries("var2", label = "Var2", fillGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = FALSE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to fill these graphs in with color?

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to color the area under the line.

Comment: thank you so much for your update - I posted another question based on the answer you provided : is there a way to adjust the color scheme of this graph? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041654/r-stacked-graph-produces-different-colors-than-non-stacked ... thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The correct option is fillGraph = TRUE, if you use stackedGraph it will give you the stacked version.

```
library(dygraphs)

dygraph(df, main = "Stacked Graph") %>%
  dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
  dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
  dyOptions(fillGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!  I posted another question based on the answer you provided : is there a way to adjust the color scheme of this graph? stackoverflow.com/questions/77041654/… ... thank you so much!